# custom list of object binding error in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

my c# class is

```
public class Otp
{
    public String Time;
    public Otp()
    {

    }
    public void setTime(String Time)
    {
      this.Time = Time;
    }

    public String getTime()
    {
        return this.Time;
    }    
}
```

my problem is when i bind a list of object to grid view it give me error how can i solve this problem?

Comment: The data source for GridView with id 'OtpGrid' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns

Comment: You can't bind fields. You need a property to bind.

Answer (score 2):

The databinding only can bind against properties and your Time is defined as a member variable. To make Time a property, define it with getter and setter:

```
public String Time { get; set; }
```

And there is no need in additional get and set methods.

Answer (score -1):

```
public String Time
    {
        get
        {
            //your code here
            return this.Time;//ex.
        }
        set
        {
            //your code here
            this.Time = Time;//ex.
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have provided no context for why or how this would help. Also, there are a stack overflow errors on your property